# Vuejs Bugs view components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this code for a component but it's not working.  It's give me an empty page when I view it in the localhost and I tried it from both of the ports 3000 and 8000.  It keeps giving me the same error, no data to show .

```html
<template>
<form>
    <a @click="addCategory" class="add">+ Add Category</a>
        <div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="category.id">
            <input type="text" v-model="category.name" :ref="category.name">
            <input type="number" v-model="category.display_order">
            <a @click="removeCategory(index)" class="remove">delete</a>
            <div>
                <img v-if="category.image" :src="'/images/${category.image}'" width="100">
                <lable v-else>Image: </lable>
                <input type="text" v-model.lazy="category.image">
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['initialCategories'],
        data() {
            return {
                categories: _.cloneDeep(this.initialCategories)
            };
        },
        methods: {
            removeCategory(index) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    this.categories.splice(index, 1);
                }
            },
            addCategory() {
                this.categories.push({
                    id: 0,
                    name: '',
                    image: '',
                    display_order: this.categories.length + 1
                });
                this.nextTick(() => {
                    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                    this.$refs[''][0].focus();
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
    hr {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

and this is the app.js file

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key)))

Vue.component('category-manager', require('./components/CategoryManager.vue'));

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

this is the view page for it

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', ' - Categories')

@section('content')
    <h1>Categories</h1>
    <category-manager :initial-categories="{{ $categories }}"></category-manager>
@endsection
```

and it looks like this [image]

** by the way I'm using Larvel 7.4 and vuejs3

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: as you I said It's doesn't view any data from the code the I wrote it up just keep giving me empty page as in image

Comment: Make sure that you have the save file structure `resources/js/components` and also you can try to uncomment those two lines 
`
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key)))
`
in your app.js file and then remove `Vue.component` line. This is used to register your components automatically without worrying about registering everyone of them

Comment: also, try to make the content of the component static just showing a bunch of text or something like this and try with it to make sure that the problem isn't from the logic used in the component, Once you see your static component in the webpage you can add your logic as you want

Comment: + most importantly, after writing your component run `npm run dev` to compile your component and add it to be able to use it in your project

Comment: I'm already running ```npm run watch```

Comment: Set the name of the component in the actual vue file. Above props[], put name: 'namegoeshere', obviously replace namegoeshere with the name of your component. You should check the browser console because it'll probably tell you what the issue is. Right click in the browser and select "Inspect element". Then go to the console tab and view the red line. Post it here so we can see